# Can't set up Unicode support

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, unicode, utf-8

I am creating a toy website locally with XAMPP and I want it to support Unicode.

index.php contains a simple form that I can use to add a new entry (a UTF-8 string) to a table "myTable" in the DB. In addition to that, I am also echoing with PHP every entry from "myTable" on the body of index.php, so that I can see if the UTF-8 strings that I am entering through the form make all the way into the database and back without any issues.

---

Here are the measures that I took toward Unicode support:

1. Every file on my website (ex.: index.php) is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM;
2. `<meta charset='utf-8'>` everywhere applicable too;
3. `mysqli_set_charset($myConnection, "utf-8");` in my "db.inc.php" file;
4. At the phpMyAdmin "control panel" (?), under "Database Server" I see "Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)";
5. I created a database and a table for this specific purpose. Here is the result of `` SHOW CREATE TABLE `myTable` ``:

   `` CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
   `row1` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
   `row2` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin ``

---

The outcome was as follows: when I print the entries of "myTable", everything does get displayed correctly on the browser indeed, **however** only owing to a stroke of luck, because apparently my strings are being internally represented badly. When I browse my table with phpMyAdmin I see mojibake, and I looked over at `myTable.ibd` and I see the same mojibake.
The string `joão e maría` for example, is displayed as `joÃ£o e marÃ­a`; for the first `ã -> Ã£`, it could be UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as latin-1, though I see `Ã£` even when I tell npp to interpret the file as UTF-8.

Running the query `` SELECT `row1`, HEX(`row1`) FROM `myTable` WHERE 1 `` I see `6A6FC383C2A36F2065206D6172C383C2AD61` as the bytes of `joÃ£o e marÃ­a`, so in fact the mojibake is "correctly" encoded as UTF-8 (`C3 83 C2 A3` is UTF-8 for `Ã£`).

Ideas?

---

### UPDATE

After more careful inspection I verified that `mysqli_set_charset($myConnection, "utf-8");` was returning `false`. I replaced it with `mysqli_set_charset($myConnection, "utf8");` and *voilà*, strings with fancy characters that I enter through the form now make it all the way into the database unscathed. However, these new strings aren't correctly displayed by the browser.

For example: the string `bênção` is inserted into the DB through the form. I query the table with `` SELECT `row`, HEX(`row1`) (...) `` and find out that it is stored as `62C3AA6EC3A7C3A36F` inside the table, which is the correct UTF-8 representation of the string in question. I access index.php and I see `b�n��o` being displayed. I download the HTML of the webpage and inspect it, and I find that the offending bytes are respectively `EA`, `E7`, `E3`, which, surely enough, correspond to `ê`, `ç` and `ã` in latin-1.

Comment: What is the charset of the web page where you are trying to display the characters? In the head section you should have `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta charset="UTF-8">` -- correct for *outside* MySQL

`utf8mb4` is the term you need to use *inside* MySQL, including

```
mysqli_set_charset($myConnection, "utf8mb4");
```

`Ã£` is Mojibake for `ã`.  This happens when `latin1` is mistakenly somewhere in the data flow.

Hex `EA E7 E3` is the the *latin1* encoding for `êçã`.
Hex `C3AA C3A7 C3A3` is the UTF-8 (utf8mb4) encoding for them.

Since you have presented different symptoms, let me present to you [*'Best Practice' and how to diagnose the symptoms*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for 'black diamond with question mark', 'Mojibake', etc.  Note that there are 4-5 places where you have to consistently use UTF-8.